# How to handle this run time type mismatch error in VB?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in MS Word comprising of dropdown list items as well as columns that display and output values depending on the combination of selected dropdown list items. I get a "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch" error when only one of the dropdown list items is selected within the set.

How would I go about handing this error?

Note: There are two dropdown lists in each set, if only one is selected and then user clicks away I would like the results column to revert to its default which is to display nothing.

I know this should be done in Excel but I have to work with what I've got, sadly.

My code works correctly and doesn't produce any errors if a non default item is selected before clicking away. However, if only an item from only one dropdown list is selected and the other dropdown list value is left as default value, the error is displayed.

Error is also displayed if I try to deselect one of the dropdown list items but not both.

Run-time error '13'
Type mismatch

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim CField As String, LField As String, RField As String, CText As String, LText As String, CRate As Double, LRate As Double, RRate As Double, RCat As String, RCatField As String
Select Case CC.Title
Case "C1", "L1"
CField = "C1"
LField = "L1"
RField = "R1"
RCatField = "RR1"

Case "C2", "L2"
CField = "C2"
LField = "L2"
RField = "R2"
RCatField = "RR2"


Case Else
Exit Sub
End Select

CText = Left(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(CField).Item(1).Range.Text, 1)
LText = Left(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(LField).Item(1).Range.Text, 1)
    If Not IsNumeric(CText) Then
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = ""
   .LockContents = True
End With
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RCatField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = ""
   .LockContents = True
End With
      End If
        If Not IsNumeric(LText) Then
      Exit Sub
      End If
      LRate = LText
      CRate = CText
      RRate = ((CRate * 3) + (LRate * 2)) * 4
      Select Case RRate
      Case Is < 41
      RCat = "Low"
      Case Is < 55
      RCat = "Moderate"
      Case Is < 70
      RCat = "High"
      Case Is >= 70
        RCat = "Catastrophic"
      End Select




With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = RRate
   .LockContents = True
End With
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RCatField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = RCat
   .LockContents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please limit your code to the relevant part (I don't think the > 200 lines of your `Case` have anything to do with your problem), and tell us which line throws the error?

Answer (score -1):

You could add an error handler to your code. Add

```
On Error GoTo errHandlr
```

Where the error occurs. 
Later, define what should happen when the error occur:

```
errHandlr:
   Debug.Print Err.Number & ":-:" & Err.Description

If Err.Number = 13 Then
    wsChange
End if

Public Function wsChange(ByVal As Range) 

  If Target.Address ="$A$1"' range of drop down list
  Range("A1").Value = "Your default  value."    'A1 should be your drop down   list address.

  End if
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I tried the code and am getting the following error message:

I am getting a Compile Error:
Sub or Function not defined


Takes me to this line of code:
 
wsChange

Comment: Maybe try to change the function wsChange to public.

Comment: I imagine the reason for the error is because the function requires an argument and the call has no argument... It's always dangerous to post untested code...